# getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) no response at all

Tags: android

I have this code on my main activity.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.startactivity);

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            ...
```

But the screen still dim after a while, any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Using `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in layout root of your activity does the same thing without extra code.

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation for `setFlags()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags%28int,%20int%29) (for which `addFlags()` is a convenience method):

> Note that some flags must be set before the window decoration is
>   created (by the first call to setContentView(View,
>   android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Meaning you should move your call to `addFlags()` to before you call `setContentView()`. @nandeesh posted this answer already but deleted it -- I am not sure why.

Comment: well i saw some apps using both ways. So i thought it was a wrong answer

Comment: Nope, you were right. :) You can undelete it if you want, I'll give it an upvote. I think only some flags require it before setContentView.

Comment: Doesnt work. I put it before setcontentview() and the screen still dim after a while..Soo frustrated.

Comment: I have discovered that the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON seems to work only when the "USB debugging" is enabled. If its not enabled, the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON is ignored.

Comment: @Ted: What you've written here and in (at least) two other questions is just wrong. We should put it right for others: `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` works perfectly for what it describes: It just makes the screen keep on. Neither is there any permission required for this to work nor does it only work if your device is in debug mode. It should work on every device, and if it doesn't, it's the device's fault ;)

Answer (score 0):

On the panasonic toughpad FZ-B2 enabling USB debugging did the trick. The screen goes on now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the flag in onAttachedToWindow() method.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```